# Is it possible to use react-router useHistory() or React useState with withFormik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state, formik

My registration form is using [withFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik).

```
const RegistrationContainer = compose<InnerProps, OuterProps>(
  withFormik<InnerProps, RegistrationValues>({
    mapPropsToValues: () => RegistrationSchema.cast(),
    validationSchema: RegistrationSchema,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    handleSubmit: async (values, bag) =>
      register(values).catch((e) => {
        if (e.errorMessage) {
          if (e.errorCode === Gigya.ErrorCode.PendingVerification) {
            useHistory().push(generatePath(ConfirmPath, { email: values.email }));
          }
          if (e.errorCode === Gigya.ErrorCode.Validation) {
            return bag.setErrors({ email: t('scene.registration.exists') });
          }
          return bag.setStatus({ errorMessage: e.errorMessage });
        }

        return null;
      }),
  })
)(ExampleForm);

export default RegistrationContainer;
```

In the `handleSubmit` I try to use `useHistory()` from `react-router`. To send `state` value to the confirmation route.

React router version: `"react-router": "^5.2.0"`

```
useHistory().push(generatePath(ConfirmPath, { email: values.email }));
```

And print them out there:

// confirmation route component:

```
const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.state);
  }, [location]);
```

But when I want to submit the form (I can't test it on my local) I get an [error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321). What's wrong?

Is it possible to use `useHistory` with `withFormik`? Or can I use React `useState` hook?

Answer (score 0):

In React Router v6, you have to swap out `useHistory` for `useNavigate`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate). Replace what you have with what I pasted below and you should be good to go.

```
useNavigate().push(generatePath(ConfirmPath, { email: values.email }));
```

Comment: thanks good option, but I can't upgrade yet to v6.